# How to print Python NLTK output from browser (within Django)

Tags: python, django, nltk

I'm using Django on RedHat's openShift platform, using Django, and trying to output NLTK results to the browser.
But when I  try to do the HttpResponse with the result, it returns null.

How do you access the NLTK calls and output the results to the browser?

I have tested the contents of the concordance function and it works when put in line by line into the Python shell.
What is different?
I've tried different things to get at the standard output.

views.py:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
import json
import nltk
import nltk.data
import pickle
import subprocess

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>intro</h2>")

def concordance(request):
    script = request.GET.get('script')
    textPath = [path to file dir]
    fullTextPath = textPath+script+'.txt'

    f=open(fullTextPath)
    raw=f.read()

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)

    result = text.concordance('love')

    return HttpResponse(result, "Content-Type: text/html")
```

from urls.py (the routing seems to be working)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'openshift.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^concordance/', 'openshift.views.concordance', name='concordance'),
```

Comment: I've narrowed things down to a NLTK function issue:
The function outputs seem to work differently than the ones I have encountered before - perhaps it's a Python thing, or perhaps it's a NLTK thing. Either way it makes it a pain at this point to output the processed results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax is:

```
return HttpResponse(result, content_type="text/html")
```

not

```
return HttpResponse(result, "Content-Type: text/html")
```

Comment: Implemented the change; but still no NLTK output

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant parts of your `urls.py` please